# How to open an UIView in fullscreen mode with a tabbar?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitabbar, modalviewcontroller

this is my problem.

1. I have a tabBar application.
2. In first tab, i have a table.
3. On click on table it shows a modal
   view.
4. To go back from modal view to first
   view, i use

> ```
> [self presentModalViewController:nw animated:YES];
> ```

The problem is that if i click on the tabbar while is opened a modal view, it opens second view, but first view's table don't work because the modal view is still opened althoug it appear as closed.

It's a way to open modal view in fullscreen covering the tab bar? 
Or also to check if modal view is closed or not from another view?

**EDIT:**
I tried with all of this code:

```
 nw = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:nil];
 nw.modalInPopover = YES;
 nw.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
 nw.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
 nw.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
 nw.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
 nw.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
 [nw.view setNeedsLayout];
```

but nothing!!! It wan't go in fullscreen!!

Any idea please?

thanks,
alberto

Comment: What view/view controller are you presenting modally?

Comment: @middaparka: is the view that flip on click on table view, and close when click [self present.....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using notification!

When a tab change, i send a notification and close the modal controller.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController { 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataComplete" object:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

In my view classes receive a notification and dismiss the controller!

```
- (void)downloadDataComplete:(NSNotification *)notif {
    NSLog(@"Received Notification");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now it's possibile to reopen a modal view also changing tab!
This is a workaround but works!

alberto.

Comment: and if you want a fullscreen, remove the uiviewcontroller object from interface builder!

Answer (score 1):

If the view you're presenting is full screen, this should obscure the tab bar. That said, you might need to re-size the view programmatically so that it's the same size as the UIWindow.

You should be able to do something along the lines of...

```
[nw setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
[nw setNeedsLayout];
```

...to achieve this. (Sorry, I'm on a Windows box at the moment, so I can't confirm this. Hopefully someone will provide any tweaks if required.)

You should then dismiss the initial modal view via a delegate method in the originating class. (See the "Dismissing a Modal View Controller" section of Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).) The originating class would then dispose of the modal view.

Comment: sorry, but i can't able to show nw in fullscreen in this way... it's the same.